# Why did they plug the drive into the network?

Tags: james-bond, skyfall

Any security person worth their salt would know that you don't plug a drive retrieved from a malicious source onto a network connected system. At least not connected to the uber-secure network.

Why did Q plug the drive into a system attached to the secure network? Why didn't he take the extremely simple and obvious precaution of disconnecting from the network before trying to read the drive?